# How to find similar strings in array and rename the strings?

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary, batch-rename

I want to find similar strings in an array/dictionary and rename them by adding a postfix to the string. For example suppose my array/dictionary contains strings like this:

```
1.Work
2.Work
3.Work
4.Home
5.Home
6.Mobile
7.Mobile
```

etc. there could be any similar strings. Now I want to rename them like this:

```
1.Work(1)
2.Work(2)
3.Work(3)
4.Home(1)
5.Home(2)
6.Mobile(1)
7.Mobile(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i don't know about a dictionary, but for an array you could do something like this.

```
    NSMutableArray *myArr = [fill the array with w/e];
    int home;
    int mobile;
    int work;
    for(int x = 0; x < [myArr count]; x++){
    NSString *r = [myArr objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)x];
    if([r isEqualToString:@"work"]){
    work++;
    [myArr replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[NSString strinWithFormat:@"%@(%i)", r, work]];
    }
    else if([r isEqualToString:@"home"]){
    home++;
    [myArr replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[NSString strinWithFormat:@"%@(%i)", r, home]];
    }
    else if([r isEqualToString:@"mobile"]){
    mobile++;

    [myArr replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:[NSString strinWithFormat:@"%@(%i)", r, mobile]];

    }
    }
```

Best of luck

Comment: there is no fix strings. there could be any string witch is identical to another

Comment: Ok, then run a preliminary function that gets all the different string then do something similar to whats above